# Plot a mirror histogram in R and deal with NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
var1 = as.data.frame(c(runif(100,2,10),rep(NA,900)))
var2 = as.data.frame(runif(1000,-1,9))

colnames(var1)<-"var1"
colnames(var2)<-"var2"

data <- cbind(var1 ,var2)
```

I want to plot the histogram of var1 and var2 in one plot, and as a mirror chart, without deleting rows from var2.

I used this code:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x) ) +
  geom_histogram( aes(x = var1, y = ..density..), fill="#69b3a2" ) +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=0.25, label="variable1"), color="#69b3a2") +
  geom_histogram( aes(x = var2, y = -..density..), fill= "#404080") +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=-0.25, label="variable2"), color="#404080") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  xlab("value of x")

p
```

and I got this chart:

[image]

but it seems that this graph doesn't include 900 values of var2 (they were deleted because we have 900 NAs in var1).

[image]

I don't want to replace the NAs with another value, because I will not have the required shape of graph,
for example I replaced the NAs with 0 and this is what I got:

```
data[is.na(data)]<-0
```

[image]

Is there any way to plot the graph with all values in the dataset, and get the required plot which should be similar to the first plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just getting confused with the warning message. The `var2` data *is* being plotted. To reassure you of this, let's modify your data frame:

```r
var1 = as.data.frame(c(runif(100,2,10), rep(NA, 900)))
var2 = as.data.frame(c(runif(100, -1, 3), runif(900, 5, 9)))
```

Now you can see that if all the rows where `var1` is `NA` are removed, you should only see `var2` values between -1 and 3. If `var2` is plotted even though `var1` is `NA`, we should also get some values between 5 and 9 being plotted for `var2`:

```
colnames(var1)<-"var1"
colnames(var2)<-"var2"

data <- cbind(var1 ,var2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x) ) +
  geom_histogram( aes(x = var1, y = ..density..), fill="#69b3a2" ) +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=0.25, label="variable1"), color="#69b3a2") +
  geom_histogram( aes(x = var2, y = -..density..), fill= "#404080") +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=-0.25, label="variable2"), color="#404080") +
  xlab("value of x")

p
```

[image]

So you don't need to worry; only the variable with missing entries will not be plotted.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.
Another question : does the "density" in the histogram represents the percentages for each range or not ?

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 no, not really. The _area_ of all the bars on the histogram (the value of their height on the y axis times their width on the x axis) should add up to one for each variable. Since the bars are of equal width, the height of the bars is _proportional_ to the percentage, but not equal to it. It is possible to bin the data into counts and divide by the total number of non-NA values to get a percentage for each bin which you could plot with `geom_col` if you wanted it that way.

Comment: Thanks @Allan I think you mean  that I may replace the y=..density.. 
with 
y=..count../sum(..count..)

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 yes, that would do it, though if you want percentage labels you would probably want to add `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`